# How to convert a clojure keyword into a string?

Tags: clojure

In my application I need to convert clojure keyword eg. :var_name into a string "var_name". Any ideas how that could be done?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

```
user=> (doc name)
-------------------------
clojure.core/name
([x])
  Returns the name String of a string, symbol or keyword.
nil
user=> (name :var_name)
"var_name"
```

Comment: I cannot imagine a more complete answer, but just for fun I shall dare someone to come up with it.

Comment: @Hamish Perhaps by adding `(source name)`?

Comment: How `name` works should not be of interest. The docstring is the contract. Anything else is an implementation detail, one should not rely upon.

Comment: Thanks! My initial reaction was to do this:                      (.replaceFirst (.toString (keyword "abc")) ":" "")

Comment: Thanks kotarak! I am loving this Clojure more every day! This is my third day.

Comment: @BartJ: `(doc subs)` => `(subs (str (keyword "abc")) 1)` ;)

Comment: Maybe this answer should explain why `(name :foo/123/bar)` is "bar". If you want the full path of a keyword you need to use `subs` or something like `(str (namespace k) "/" (name k))`

Answer (score 18):

Actually, it's just as easy to get the namespace portion of a keyword:

```
(name :foo/bar)  => "bar"
(namespace :foo/bar) => "foo"
```

Note that namespaces with multiple segments are separated with a '.', not a '/'

```
(namespace :foo/bar/baz) => throws exception: Invalid token: :foo/bar/baz
(namespace :foo.bar/baz) => "foo.bar"
```

And this also works with namespace qualified keywords:

```
;; assuming in the namespace foo.bar
(namespace ::baz) => "foo.bar"  
(name ::baz) => "baz"
```

Answer (score 15):

Note that kotarak's answer won't return the namespace part of keyword, just the name part - so :

```
(name :foo/bar)
>"bar"
```

Using his other comment gives what you asked for :

```
(subs (str :foo/bar) 1)
>"foo/bar"
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not a tedious task to convert any data type into a string, Here is an example by using **str**.

```
(defn ConvertVectorToString []
 (let [vector [1 2 3 4]]
 (def toString (str vector)))
  (println toString)
  (println (type toString)
(let [KeyWordExample (keyword 10)]
 (def ConvertKeywordToString (str KeyWordExample)))
  (println ConvertKeywordToString)
  (println (type ConvertKeywordToString))

(ConvertVectorToString) ;;Calling ConvertVectorToString Function

Output will be:
1234
java.lang.string
10
java.lang.string
```

Answer (score -3):

This will also give you a string from a keyword:

```
(str (name :baz)) -> "baz"
(str (name ::baz)) -> "baz"
```

Comment: `str` is not needed in your example.